# Save WordSearch Generator Variable to CSV file

Tags: python, csv, save, wordsearch

I´m learning programming in phyton and i had to make a wordsearch generator. Ive made it but i need the result to be saved in a csv file. Ive tried a lot but cant seem to find out how, anyone can help me please? Thanks in advance.

```
import random

def mayor_a_10(numero):
    return int(numero) > 10
    
def pedir_dato(texto):
    dato = input(texto)
    if(mayor_a_10(dato) == True):
        return dato
    else:
        pedir_dato("ERROR. Ingrese un número mayor a 10: ")
        
def pedir_datos_tablero():
    palabras = []
    max_palabras = int(N) / 3
    
    palabra = input("Ingrese una palabra o escriba 'fin' para terminar: ")
    palabras.append(str(palabra))
    
    while(palabra != "fin" and len(palabras) < int(max_palabras)):
        palabra = input("Ingrese otra palabra o escriba 'fin' para terminar: ")
        palabras.append(str(palabra))
        
    return palabras
        
def generar_tablero(N, palabras):
    matriz = []
    filas  = int(N)
    columnas = int(N)
    letras =['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    
    for i in range(filas):
        matriz.append([0] * columnas)
    
    for f in range(filas):
        for c in range(columnas):
            letra_random = random.randint(0,24) 
            matriz[f][c] = letras[letra_random]
            
    for x in matriz:
        print(x)
            
# Programa principal
pedir_dato("Ingrese un número mayor a 10: ")

N = input("Ingrese un número mayor o igual a 15 para la cantidad de columnas y filas: ")
while(int(N) < 5):
    N = input("ERROR. Ingrese un número mayor o igual a 15 para las columnas y filas: ")

palabras = pedir_datos_tablero()
tablero = generar_tablero(N, palabras)
```

[image]

In the variable tablero is my wordsearch finished, that is what i want to export to csv.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to your code should work:

```
f = open("myfile.csv",'w')
csv = ''
for i in tablero:
    csv += i+','
f.write(csv[:-1])
f.close()
```

Comment: I got this error, Se produjo una excepción: TypeError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
'NoneType' object is not iterable
  File "C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\sopa de letras python\sopa.py", line 57, in <module> (Current frame)
    for i in tablero:

Comment: @PabloRomanelli is `tablero` an array?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, i think it is an array. I managed to add the program to the main post, maybe its easier to help that way. Sorry for bothering.